# How can I limit the number of rows updated in a JPQL query?

Tags: java, jpql

I want to limit this update query to only update 5 rows:

```
Query updateQuery = em.createQuery("update Entity e SET e.myVar = 1");
updateQuery.setMaxResults(5).executeUpdate();
```

`setMaxResults` does not seem to do the job.  How can I do this in jpql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If portability is not a issue, then you can go for database specific native query.

- Oracle : `em.createNativeQuery("update TableName SET myVar = 1 where id IN (SELECT id FROM TableName WHERE ROWNUM <= 5)").executeUpdate();`
- MySql : `em.createNativeQuery("update TableName SET myVar = 1 where id IN (SELECT id FROM TableName LIMIT 5)").executeUpdate();`

**ROWNUM** & **LIMIT** are used to limit number of results in a query for Oracle & MySql respectively.

Haven't mentioned which database you are using. Provided sample-code might help you, make alterations accordingly.

Comment: This is helpful and an answer but I really needed a platform independent way of doing this.

Comment: Can try Criteria API using subqueries where in subquery you can restrict the number of results to be fetched by setMaxResults(size) & then updating those records in main query. Else without it can go with two queries, one for retrieving specific number of records & then updating them.